# Switching between consoles

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm happy to use WSL2 with Ubuntu on my Windows machine. But how to switch between consoles? <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> not work anymore. I'm using Windows terminal to connect to WSL Ubuntu.

Comment: Does WSL even support that? Are there any consoles to connect to?

Answer (score 0):

While <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, et. al., won't work under WSL, there are a few alternatives.

Each "console" in Windows Terminal is just a separate tab.  Just hit the drop-down menu (<kbd>**∨**</kbd>) and select your WSL profile there.  Assuming you are using the default keybindings for Windows Terminal, the keys chords to select a tab are *close* to those of a Linux console -- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (numerals, rather than function keys).  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will also work there.  I'm guessing you could even assign the function keys as bindings for switching tabs as well.

You could even set up a startup script for Windows Terminal that automatically allocated 7 WSL profile tabs, so that they would always be available.  Note that exiting a session, however, would close the tab.  There's no concept of "returning to login" in WSL; really there's just no concept of "login".

Alternatively, I would propose `tmux` for managing multiple shell sessions in WSL (it's already installed by default in the Ubuntu distributions on WSL).  Then you would just start WSL once, with something like `wsl tmux`.  That would give you the ability to create new `tmux` windows/consoles at will.  It also provides keyboard based scrollback, along with a myriad of other features.